# what is a wrong in this code?

Tags: c++, string

i have following code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
string replace(string s){

    for (int i=0;i<s.length();i++){
        if (s[i]> 'b' &&  s[i]<'f'){
            s.erase(s[i]);

        }

    }
    return  s;
}
int main(){

    string s;
    cin>>s;
    cout<<replace(s)<<endl;


    return 0;

}
```

if i enter georgia it show me exception  "abort was called" why?

Comment: what ereOn says and also you have a bug. if you have for example "cca", only first c will be removed.

Comment: @Pasi Savolainen: If you input `"cca"` in his code, it invokes undefined behavior.

Answer (score 6):

`std::string::erase()` takes either an index pair, or iterators.

Look at [this link](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/string/erase).

Here `s[i]` gives a char, which is mistakenly converted to a `size_t` so, depending on your string, you basically try to remove an element that doesn't exist.

A cleaner solution would be:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

bool should_be_removed(char c) { return (c > 'b') && (c < 'f'); }

int main()
{
  std::string s;
  std::cin >> s;
  s.erase(std::remove_if(s.begin(), s.end(), should_be_removed), s.end());

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Nice solution, but shouldn't `remove_if` be called `partition` or something since it doesn't actually remove anything nut just moves things about a bit. There's probably a really good reason for that name though.

Comment: @Skizz: it doesn't necesarily moves the "removed" elements, it just moves the elements that don't match. The values of the elements after the iterator returned by `remove_if` are undefined.

Comment: yes, you're right. I had to re-read the spec for `remove_if` carefully.